# How to render "latest posts" from post array ? (Vue.js)

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I am building a blog app and I want to render latest posts on the homepage, I am using Vue with Nuxt and Storyblok for the backend/cms.

At the moment I am displaying all my post from the posts array is there a way only to display a number of posts or even better dispaly latests posts from the posts array?

```
<template>
  <section class="container">
    <PostList :posts="loadedPosts" class="post-list" />
  </section>
</template>


export default {
  components: {
    PostList,
    Aside
  },

  computed: {
    loadedPosts() {
      return this.$store.getters.loadedPosts.map(bp => {
        return {
          id: bp.slug,
          title: bp.content.title,
          previewText: bp.content.summary,
          thumbnailUrl: bp.content.thumbnail
        };
      });
    }
  }
```

I would like to get the last 3-4 posts from my loaded posts.

Comment: If the array is ordered by latest post is the last value in the array you could use: `let latestPost = myArray[myArray.length - 1]` If the posts aren't ordered in the array i would recommend checking for a date property on the posts and either sort the list by date or using a conditional to return the value you want.

Comment: Sorry the question wasn't asked properly. I need a list of latest posts from my loadedPosts. I've edited the question now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this.$store.getters.loadedPosts` seems to be an array. To get only the first 4 items you would have to slice it (assuming the lastest post is the first in the array).

```
loadedPosts() {
  return this.$store.getters.loadedPosts.slice(0, 4).map(bp => {
    return {
      id: bp.slug,
      ...
    };
  });
}
```